# VECM with Multicollinearity

Tags: multicollinearity, vector-error-correction-model, macroeconomics, identifiability

I have fit a vector error correction model (VECM) to some macroeconomic data. In particular, I am interested in three relationships

1. real GDP as a function of employment and real wages
2. employment as a function of the labor force
3. money as a function of real GDP, prices, and interest rates

I can estimate a VECM using real GDP, employment, real wages, labor force, money, prices, and interest rates using the above to motivate three potential cointegrating relationships.

However, I started thinking about simple GDP decompositions, like Y=C+I+G+NX. The problem is that if I just add the additional variables (and another cointegrating relationship), then multicollinearity becomes an issue because real GDP is essentially defined by these other variables (with US data chaining means it's not perfect, but close enough).

What is the best way to handle this type of issue? Drop one of the variables? Which one?